# dual monitors in full screen mode & have one verticaly rotated

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors

Hi is it possible to have dual monitors in full screen mode & have one verticaly rotated upside down Whilst the other is normal (I know that it can be done in extended mode.)

Answer (score 1):

It very much depends on graphics card options. If your card has more than one output, then it should be accomplished with the graphics card driver/software. I know ATi HydraVision and Nvidia control panel applet could do that. You may want to upgrade your graphics driver to the latest AND check with the manufacturer web site whether they do support this option or not.

Regards,
Taavi

Comment: Windows 7 supports this natively, there's no need to use the manufacturer apps.